# PHP sessions do not work inside do not include()

Tags: php

I have a project where the user, after logged in, generates a session and this session I get inside header.php.

**header.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

 list($nomeAdmin,$sobreNAdmin) = explode(" ",$_SESSION['NomeAcesso']);
  
 echo "Hello, " .$nomeAdmin;

 ?>
```

This file is dynamic and I put it inside an include on the pages of this project.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

...

include("includes/header.php");

...

?>
```

The problem is that although the session is working correctly, within the include it does not work.How can I fix this?

Comment: First of all: Don’t start a session _twice_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started session twice therefore remove the session from header.php page & then try to print the session on the header page.

Comment: Thank you all. I paid no attention to that detail. It worked!